# command to get selected file name in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Consider case that my batch file test.bat resides at c:\test location . But while browsing I goto folder c:\different_folder . 
I select this different_folder. 
Now I want command which will give me full path of this different_folder.

I want to use that command into test.bat file.

Comment: Are you using Windows Explorer? If so, you cannot browse to `c:\different_folder` and then select it. You can only select a folder while viewing it from its parent folder. Could you be a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo %CD%
```

This command will the current directory's full path.